# Python Access Granted

Tags: python

I was given this program and it works.

```
#######################################################################
## This program simulates a login screen.
## The username and passwords are stored in an input file.
#######################################################################

f=open('usernames.txt')
usernames=[]
passwords=[]

for index in range(10):
    line = f.readline().strip()
    usernames.append(line)
    line = f.readline().strip()  
    passwords.append(line)

user = input("Username: ")
found = False
for index in range(10):
     if user == usernames[index]:
         found = True
         passwrd = input("Password: ")
         if passwrd == passwords[index]:
             print("Access Granted")
         else :
             print("Username and password do not match")
         break
if (not found):
    print("Username not found")
```

I need to modify this program so that it repeatedly asks for a valid username and password until access is granted. I think this is supposed to be really simple and the reason why I'm having so much trouble is the fact that I don't understand why the call of `strip()` needs to be there. I don't understand how the program is matching an index of the text file with the index directly after it.

Comment: `strip` function just removes space characters from both side of a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('usernames.txt', 'r')  # you must to setup mode of opening file each time. In this case mode 'r'- read
usernames = []
granted = False

for line in f:
    # read file line by line
    usernames.append(line.strip())

if len(usernames) % 2 != 0:
    # checking that file have even numbers of lines
    print('Bad input file. Last string will be ignored')
    usernames.pop()  # removing of last string

def auth():
    user = input("Username: ")
    try:  # with try we can catch any exceptions
        index = usernames.index(user)   # check that our list have username and get index of it
        if index % 2 != 0:  # checking that it username
            print("Username not found")
            return False
    except:  # if usernames is not contained user string we catch of exception
        print("Username not found")
        return False

    passwrd = input("Password: ")
    if passwrd == usernames[index+1]:
        print("Access Granted")
        return True

    else:
        print("Username and password do not match")
        return False

while not granted:
    granted = auth()
```